# how to replace margin-left to margin-inline-start programmatically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a multi-language project. I want to change all the used margin-left styles to margin-inline-start, after the direction of the `<body>` changed according to the selected language. how can I do it programmatically in javaScript?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can try to loop through computed style, retrieve margin-left value, reset margin-left and then apply a margin-inline-start with the value of margin left.

here is the basic idea : (Live Demo at https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWrGBjX?editors=1111 )

```js
let allelements = document.querySelectorAll("body  *");
for (i = 0; i < allelements.length; i++) {
  let computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(allelements[i]);
  // look for
  if (computedStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-left") != "0px") {
    let valMargin = computedStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-left");
    // let's see what's going on, if anything happens
    console.log(
      "found margin-left. value : " +
      computedStyle.getPropertyValue("margin-left") +
      " of " +
      allelements[i].tagName
    );
    //reset
    allelements[i].style.marginLeft = "auto";
    // set/reset  inline-start margin
    allelements[i].style.marginInlineStart = valMargin;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
}

h1,
p,
code {
  margin-left: 10em;
}
```

```html
<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>

                <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

                <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

                <ol>
                   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                </ol>

                <blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

                <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

                <ul>
                   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                </ul>

                <pre><code>
                #header h1 a {
                  display: block;
                  width: 300px;
                  height: 80px;
                }
                </code></pre>
```

I'm not an developper, so that might not be the most effective way to do it.

---

But starting from here, you will probably find out that margin-right maybe needs to be reset too, and so floats....

If you use a flex or grid-layout, without margin , but justify/align , you will not have to bother about the direction / dir value of the document , the browser will follow it naturally ;)